# Music database like IMDb

Tags: api, music

Looking for a public music DB Api, where a music title / author of music are submitted and it returns cover photo and sample of the song can be downloaded for listening. Something like IMDb for movies. Does anything exists?

Found this list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_online_music_databases).

Comment: It seems like you've answered your own question? (discogs.com is my go to)

Answer (score 2):

By far the largest music resource is [MusicBrainz](https://musicbrainz.org/). It will return the cover photo; I'm not sure about the sample. AllMusic and Discogs have been mentioned. Spotify has an [API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/), I think it is worth checking it, as well as [lastfm](http://www.last.fm/api)'s. Hope this helps!